# keepalived IP filter?

Tags: load-balancer, keepalive

I am using keepalived to load-balance connections to 4 servers.

Is there any way to route all non-logged-in users to one server and all logged-in users to the other 3 servers?

I can update a list/csv/database on the load balancer that runs keepalived with the IPs of logged in users.

I've been looking everywhere but couldn't find any effective solution.

Thanks